# How do I resolve "Cannot invoke the SendConfigurationApply method." when performing Start-DscConfiguration?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, dsc

#### Another way to phrase the question less specifically: What is the correct way to 'reset' the DSC processes on a target machine?

I've created a DSC configuration that I'm iterating on right now, and I am adding new Package configuration which I've gotten wrong. I determined that by forgetting to supply the /quiet argument to an MSI installer in a Package block I can cause the Start-DscConfiguration cmdlet to 'hang'.

At the onset of this 'hang' I stop the DSC configuration operation on my local machine and attempt to correct the configuration problem (by adding the /quiet argument in my example) then I restart the DSC operation. Now I am seeing the following for my remote machines during the operation:

```
Cannot invoke the SendConfigurationApply method. The PerformRequiredConfigurationChecks method is in progress and must return before SendConfigurationApply can be invoked.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
    + PSComputerName        : REMOTEMACHINE20
```

Unfortunately, visiting the remote PC being configured I see a similar error message, and rebooting the PC doesn't seem to rectify the error.

I've seen some posts online regarding this problem, and the three I've found thus far suggest:

1. "Just wait a while and it will resolve itself", which hasn't worked for me (maybe I'm impatient...). Not a tenable long-term solution.
2. "Delete all local .mof files and try again", which hasn't worked for me either.
3. [Stop all processes with 'wmi' in the name and restart the winrm service on the target machine(s).](http://www.beefycode.com/post/A-Bit-of-DSC-Frustration.aspx) This has gotten me unblocked, but I am hopeful there is a better way to do this. *(If I don't hear a better method in the next few days I'll answer this myself with this procedure to get the results required).*

Comment: I had the same problem, and solution 3 is the one I found which worked for me as well. None of the others did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try executing the start-dscconfiguration command with the -Force option

```
Start-DscConfiguration -Force ...
```

Comment: Since I posted this original question, I have done a lot of learning on DSC. This is indeed the correct answer for this issue. When did the -Force switch show up? (Doesn't matter, but it would be good to have it here for posterity going forward).

Answer (score 21):

I've found the following works pretty well to reset DSC. Note this will delete the local configuration, so you will need to re-apply the machinename.meta.mof file.

```
#Remove all mof files (pending,current,backup,MetaConfig.mof,caches,etc)
rm C:\windows\system32\Configuration\*.mof*
#Kill the LCM/DSC processes
gps wmi* | ? {$_.modules.ModuleName -like "*DSC*"} | stop-process -force
```

At this point you have a clean system ready to be configured using `Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager` and updated using `Update-DscConfiguration -Wait -Verbose -CimSession machinename`

So far the only thing this hasn't fixed is a corrupted $env:psmodulepath or missing scheduled tasks for Consistency/Reboot checks. **Update:** According to [this item on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1218551) the scheduled tasks for Consistency/Reboot were removed in the WMF 5.0 February preview.

Comment: Thanks, after 2 hours pulling my hair out, your answer finally got DSC working again.

Comment: An alternative to removing all MOF files is to use Remove-DscConfigurationDocument -Stage Pending -Force. This will remove a hung configuration that is in progress. Also, I had to kill all processes prior to removal as it didn't let me remove the document without killing the processes.